# How to change the foreground color of ttk.Button when its state is active?

Tags: python, colors, ttk

I have a `ttk.Button` which color I want to change.

I did it in the following way:

```
Style().configure('gray.TButton', foreground='black', background='gray')              
backButton = Button(self.bottomFrame, text="Back",
                       command=lambda: controller.ShowFrame("StartPage"),  
                       style='gray.TButton')      
backButton.pack(side='left')
```

And it works fine (screenshot):

[image]

But if this widget in the active mode (mouse cursor within it) it looks bad. Background becomes white so text becomes invisible.

**Question**: How to change text-color in *active* mode?

**EDIT1**: After this:

```
class BackSubmit(MainFrame):                             

def __init__(self, parent, controller, title):       
  MainFrame.__init__(self, parent, controller, title)

  Style().configure('gray.TButton', foreground='white', background='gray')                  
  backButton = Button(self.bottomFrame, text="Back",
                      command=lambda: controller.ShowFrame("StartPage"),
                      style='gray.TButton')          
  backButton.bind( '<Enter>', self.UpdateFgInAcSt )                                         
  backButton.pack(side='left')                       

  Style().configure('blue.TButton', foreground='blue', background='light blue')
  submitButton = Button(self.bottomFrame,            
                        text="Submit settings",   
                        command=lambda: self.submitSettings(),
                        style='blue.TButton')        
  submitButton.pack(side=RIGHT)                      

def submitSettings(self):                            
  raise NotImplementedError("Subframe must implement abstract method")

def UpdateFgInAcSt(self, event):                     
  backButton.configure(activeforeground='gray')
```

I get the error:

`backButton.configure(activeforeground='gray')
NameError: global name 'backButton' is not defined`.

Comment: As I said in the chatroom, wirte `self.backButton` everywhere instead of `backButton`. This will fix the error message you got

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### First approach: 2 functions bound to 2 different events

You need to play around with [tkinter events.](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

`Enter` and `Leave` events will fully satisfy your goals if you create 2 corresponding functions as follows:

```
def update_bgcolor_when_mouse_enters_button(event):
    backButton.configure(background='black') # or whatever color you want

def update_bgcolor_when_mouse_leaves_button(event):
    backButton.configure(background='gray')
```

Then bind these 2 functions to your button:

```
backButton.bind('<Enter>', update_bgcolor_when_mouse_enters_button)
backButton.bind('<Leave>', update_bgcolor_when_mouse_leaves_button)
```

You can do the same with the color of the text instead of the background color of the button but using the `foreground` option instead.

#### Cheaper approach: 1 function bound to 1 event

A cheaper approach consists in using only the `Enter` event and playing on the [`activeforground`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) option instead.

Here you need to define only one function:

```
def update_active_foreground_color_when_mouse_enters_button(event):
   backButton.configure(activeforeground='gray')
```

Then bind this function to the `Enter` event as follows:

```
backButton.bind('<Enter>', update_active_foreground_color_when_mouse_enters_button)
```

Comment: Where is ``event`` argument used in your functions?

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand the logic behind your functions. Are they must know about ``backButton`` at moment of their definition?

Comment: Those functions are called events handlers. When the `backButton` witnesses the `Leave` or `Enter` events, the corresponding event handler is called and executed. If you remove the `event` argument you will get a `TypeError` exception. In your typical case, you do not need to *explicitly* use the event argument.

Comment: *I do not understand the logic behind your functions.* that is why I provided you a link to study by yourself. When you study it and still do not understand then you may come back to ask what you precisely do not understand. But your comment implies that I must reproduce what is written in that tutorial. For *Are they must know about backButton before their definition?* I think it is obvious from a Python perspective and most importantly I encourage you to write an  [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ``backButton`` is declared inside ``__init__`` function of some class. I do not want to define some extraneous function there.

Comment: Inside a class, you can define as many functions as you want. You call them by prefixing them by `self`

Comment: With some editions it works fine. The idea deserves acceptance.